# Will elementary run well on this machine?

Tags: hardware

During this week i've been trying to install a Linux distro on my old computer to give it a new life. I tried with a lot of distros like: Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Linux Mint. But all these run slow when I'm in the browser, task who left me with 50MB free. The one who ran faster was Lubuntu. I was guessing that was for the LXDE Desktop. So I want to know if this OS will run on this machine:

-RAM: 2048MB

-Processor: AMD Turion (tm) 64 Mobile Technology ML-34 (1.8GHz)

-Graphic Card: NVIDIA GeForce FX5200 Ultra (524MB)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A Sony VAIO VGN-NR120E which has very similar specs (except integrated GPU and Intel Pentium T2310) and runs elementary smoothly other than flickering when closing or opening a window

Answer (score 0):

Try a more lightweight distro. Lubuntu is one step on the right track.
Puppy Linux, Tiny Core, etc. will run on very low spec hardware.